# How to achieve scrollable canvas in Flutter?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a experienced iOS developer, but completely new to the Flutter. Right now I'm facing a problem with ScrollView in Flutter.

What I want to achieve is building a large scrollable canvas. I did it on iOS before, you can see the screenshot here.

[image: iOS UI]

The canvas is a big UIScrollView, and each subview on the canvas is draggable, so I can place them at will. Even if the text is very long, I can scroll the canvas to see the full content. Now I need to do the same thing using Flutter.

Currently, I can only drag the text widgets in Flutter. But the parent widget is not scrollable. I know I need to use a scrollable widget in Flutter to achieve the same result, but I just can't make it work. Here's the code I currently have.

```
void main() {
  //debugPaintLayerBordersEnabled = true;
  //debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Drag Box'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text(title),
    ),
    body: DragBox(Offset(0.0, 0.0)));
  }
}

class DragBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Offset position; // widget's position
  DragBox(this.position);

  @override
  _DragBoxState createState() => new _DragBoxState();
}

class _DragBoxState extends State<DragBox> {
  Offset _previousOffset;
  Offset _offset;
  Offset _position;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _offset = Offset.zero;
    _previousOffset = Offset.zero;
    _position = widget.position;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
      color: Colors.white24,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
        buildDraggableBox(1, Colors.red, _offset)
      ],
    )
  );
}

Widget buildDraggableBox(int boxNumber, Color color, Offset offset) {
  print('buildDraggableBox $boxNumber !');
  return new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Positioned(
        left: _position.dx,
        top: _position.dy,
        child: Draggable(
          child: _buildBox(color, offset),
          feedback: _buildBox(color, offset),
          //childWhenDragging: _buildBox(color, offset, onlyBorder: true),
          onDragStarted: () {
            print('Drag started !');
            setState(() {
              _previousOffset = _offset;
            });
            print('Start position: $_position}');
          },
          onDragCompleted: () {
            print('Drag complete !');
          },
          onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
            // update position here
            setState(() {
              Offset _offset = Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy - 80);
              _position = _offset;
              print('Drag canceled position: $_position');
            });
          },
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
}

Widget _buildBox(Color color, Offset offset, {bool onlyBorder: false}) {
  return new Container(
    child: new Text('Flutter widget',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25.0)),
    );
  }
}
```

Any suggestions or code samples would be really helpful to me.

PS: Please forget about the rulers on the screenshot, it's not the most important thing to me right now. I just need a big scrollable canvas now.

Comment: What does "big" mean?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot ah，my bad. just means the scrollview will occupy nearly the entire screen. I‘ll fix the wording.

Comment: You could wrap your view into a SingleChildScollView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below Code may help to resolve your problem it scroll the custom canvas in horizontal direction as you have shown in example image.

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

      class MyScroll extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: new ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Canvas Scroller'),
          );
        }
      }
      class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
        MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
        final String title;

        @override
        _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
      }
      class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
          final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: new Center(
              child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: new CustomPaint(
                  painter: new MyCanvasView(),
                  size: new Size(width*2, height/2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }

      class MyCanvasView extends CustomPainter{
        @override
        void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
          var paint = new Paint();
          paint..shader = new LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.yellow[700], Colors.redAccent],
             begin: Alignment.centerRight, end: Alignment.centerLeft).createShader(new Offset(0.0, 0.0)&size);
          canvas.drawRect(new Offset(0.0, 0.0)&size, paint);
          var path = new Path();
          path.moveTo(0.0, size.height);
          path.lineTo(1*size.width/4, 0*size.height/4);
          path.lineTo(2*size.width/4, 2*size.height/4);
          path.lineTo(3*size.width/4, 0*size.height/4);
          path.lineTo(4*size.width/4, 4*size.height/4);
          canvas.drawPath(path, new Paint()..color = Colors.yellow ..strokeWidth = 4.0 .. style = PaintingStyle.stroke);
        }

        @override
        bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
          return false;
        }

      }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've already achieved my goals. SingleChindScrollView is the way. btw your custom painting looks interesting.